Repeating string to put in various places in HTML file?
I am using GitHub to work on an HTML project that is then hosted on GitHub sites.
In order to follow which version is currently live and which version I currently am working on, a line in the footer of the website shows "Version 1.0.3". I use the same version number at the end of script imports in the  of my HTML file. This allows me to force the update of the javascript files in cache, e.g.:
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/script_1.js?v=1.0.3"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script_2.js?v=1.0.3"></script>

Before I push a new commit, I need to modify the version number on these three separate places. Is there a way I can declare it somewhere as a variable, and append it to the src of my script imports, and inside the body of my page, in the footer?
Thank you!

Every time I push a new commit, I need to modify the version number on these three separate places.
So, typically dev's will do this before publishing to the version control system, Git. This is basic string manipulation. In terms of how, depends on your dev setup/server.

Sorry, I meant that I want to modify it every time before pushing a new commit. I am using WebStorm for the development. I could run a small Python code to modify the string automatically... but if there was a variable I could declare somewhere in the HTML file or in Javascript, that would be neat!
